# How to add a whole layout withing main layout in android

Tags: android, layout, layoutparams

I've tried following code to add two layouts within main layout
but this gives error while setting layout to frame and while adding it into view

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

FrameLayout rootLayout;
FrameLayout frame1,frame2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rootLayout=new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
    frame1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.layout.frame1);
    frame2=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.layout.frame2);

    LayoutParams param1=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(180,300);
    LayoutParams param2=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(180,300);

    param1.gravity=Gravity.LEFT;
    param2.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;

    param1.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
    param2.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 30);


    frame1.setLayoutParams(param1);
    frame2.setLayoutParams(param2);

    rootLayout.addView(frame1);
    rootLayout.addView(frame2);

}
}
```

Comment: Post the error/LogCat you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove both `frame1` and `frame2` Views from their parent `View`...

and this may help you...

```
    FrameLayout rootLayout;
    FrameLayout frame1, frame2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rootLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frame1 = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frame1,null);
        frame2 = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frame2, null);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams param1 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(180, 300);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(180, 300);

        param1.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        param2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

        param1.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30);
        param2.setMargins(30, 0, 0, 30);

        frame1.setLayoutParams(param1);
        frame2.setLayoutParams(param2);

        rootLayout.addView(frame1);
        rootLayout.addView(frame2);
        setContentView(rootLayout);
    }
```

Comment: This will not help because frame1 and frame2 are altogether different layout files

Comment: if they are different layouts, how can you call findViewById() in MainActivity?